# Postgresql Transaction ID Not Found

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Whenever I am executing a query in postgresql, this is the error message I receive

> Transaction ID not found in the session.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? I recently created a new user, but I was unable to find documentation that even shows this as a valid error.

Additional Details:
I've managed to resolve the error by re-connecting with admin credentials.

I was using PG Admin V4 with Postgres V9.6, and that was the only message appearing in any query I executed, even if it was a basic query like 'SELECT NOW()'.

At the same time, this was the error message being received by the client device (an iOS device with a AWS Lambda / NodeJS backend) :

```
'message' : {
  'name' : 'error',
  'length' : 114,
  'severity' : 'fatal',
  'code' : '28000',
  'file' : 'miscinit.c',
  'line' : '587',
  'routine' : 'InitializeSessionUserId'
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: @BradChou - I usually resolve it by just opening a new query window. It works. As to the cause of the error it still remains a mystery to me.

Comment: @VKarthik, It works for me also. Thanks.

Comment: @VKarthik.. Thx for solution.. _/\\_

Answer (score 30):

I assume you found a solution, but for anyone else that finds this post, I had the same issue and I just closed PG Admin 4 and restarted it and it cleared up.

Answer (score 21):

For me helped changing 'localhost' in connection settings to '127.0.0.1', as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59747781/2590805

Answer (score 20):

### To anyone who has this problem, all you have to do is:

`1) Reconnect to the database`

`2) Open a new Query Tab. (Run your query here)`

You're welcome.

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again" sigh ... this worked for me

Comment: Does anyone know specifically why this occurs and why restarting pg admin works?

Answer (score 2):

Disconnecting and reconnecting to the database solved this issue for me; it wasn't necessary to exit/open PGAdmin 4 completely.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new **Query editor tab**, that works for me

Answer (score 1):

This is not a PostgreSQL error message. It must come from something else in the stack you are using - a client driver, ORM, etc.

Please post a more detailed question with full information on the stack you're using.

Comment: It's from pgAdmin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: few seconds before every SQL worked without trouble and then run into the same result "Transaction ID not found in the session."
As described serveral times before, a restart of pgadmin solved the problem.

I use pgadmin 6.2, belonging to the thread it seems to be an ongoing problem. Maybe someone has an idea about the reason?

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know the exact specifics of my solution, but I found this issue in the following circumstance:

- Database user was created.
- Role was assigned for the user.
- A transaction was used

I'm still not entirely sure I discovered the solution of the root problem, but if others have the same scenario, it might help troubleshoot it further. If any of those three are not used, then I never encountered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone found an explanation for this problem? I am also getting a "Transaction ID not found in the session.". It's for a long running (several days) query. I ran it on a 10% sample of my data and had no trouble, but now need to repeat the process for the full dataset. I reconnect to the database and the query appears as still active. A new idle query appears as follows:

```
SELECT rel.oid, rel.relname AS name,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_trigger WHERE tgrelid=rel.oid AND tgisinternal = FALSE) AS triggercount,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_trigger WHERE tgrelid=rel.oid AND tgisinternal = FALSE AND tgenabled = 'O') AS has_enable_triggers,
    (CASE WHEN rel.relkind = 'p' THEN true ELSE false END) AS is_partitioned
FROM pg_class rel
    WHERE rel.relkind IN ('r','s','t','p') AND rel.relnamespace = 2200::oid
    AND NOT rel.relispartition
        ORDER BY rel.relname;
```