# Postgresql Transaction ID Not Found in the session(for a large table)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

This is not a duplicate of [Postgresql Transaction ID Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220148/postgresql-transaction-id-not-found)

***I do not have any issue with small tables***, but there is a huge table about (4TB) and am trying to copy it from a db to another both located in RDS AWS (Postgresql), after a day or two I receive this message with no additional warning/message and **I have to Connect again.** 
I am using pgAdmin 4 v3.

***Transaction ID not found in the session.***

```
    SET tcp_keepalives_idle = 60 ;

  select 
 "k","LP_FK","ASSET_PK","Distance" 
 ,"Order",pk into t22 from 
 dblink('address.address port=1111
 user=user  
 password=password dbname=DB', 'select 
 "k","LP_FK","ASSET_PK","Distance" 
 ,"Order",pk   FROM  one_view_feature  ') tt ( 
"k" integer,
 "LP_FK" integer,
"ASSET_PK" integer,
"Distance" double precision,
"Order" double precision,
pk bigint)
```

As the worst case scenario, I might transfer data in different bunches, but I am sure it will be very slow.

Comment: How long does the process take?

Comment: Well, As it is not a quick query I have to leave it running. As I mentioned I notice that error after a day or two (maybe 24 hrs)- I have tried several times with this large table but no success (Same error).

Comment: Is strange, as if transactions remain pending and are killed after some time. Do you happen to open a lot of transactions for doing your work?

Comment: why would you not try running it server side with psql?..

Comment: Not necessarily by me. The db is shared so my colleagues might run some queries (maybe two or three heavy queries ) , but I am 100 sure they are not running that against this table.

Comment: also - selecting 4TB table over dblink?.. not sure it's optimal

Comment: @VaoTsun, I can give it a shot if you think this is helpful, but since RDS comes as a docker in AWS, I might have the same problem

Comment: @mohsenhs - ah! RDS! stupid suggestion then :)

Comment: :), What other options do I have with this 4TB?