# Can't query data on pgAdmin 4 but it works using psql and Python

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgadmin, dbeaver

I have created a postgresql database on rds and I can connect and query it using psql on terminal or sqlalchemy on Python. When using pgAdmin4 I can't query or visualize the data but can create/alter tables, import data, ...

I have also tried connecting it to Metabase and DBeaver but the connection times out.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I have also connected the database using pgAdmin3 and was able to visualize the data and query it, but since I am using postgresql 11.4 it is not fully supported by pgAdmin3.

When I open the query tool on pgAdmin 4 I get this message:

> could not send data to server. Socket is not connected could not send
>   startup packet: Socket is not connected.

Comment: Are you running this locally? Is it possible that once client is using a unix socket while another is using tcp?

Comment: @g_bor I am running it locally, only the database is in aws...

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311978/aws-rds-and-pgadmin4-unable-to-connect-to-server-could-not-connect-to-server

Comment: If the above solves your problem, mark it as a duplicate please.

Comment: @g_bor thanks, but it does not resolve my problem, since I can connect to the database, I just can't query it...

Answer (score 44):

Helped me:
changing 'localhost' in connection settings to '127.0.0.1'

Comment: It worked! Have you any idea why this happens?

Comment: thanks a ton buddy... I was struggling with this issue in pgadmin4 tunneling through tabby.
"... socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057) could not send startup packet."

Comment: Worked for me when trying to connect using PgAdmin 4 in Windows connecting to PgSQL in WSL2.

Comment: This sounds so absurd that I didn't even want to try it, but it WORKED

Answer (score 0):

Disconnecting from server, Changing the connection -Host to localhost under properties, fixed it for me, running PgAdmin 4 in windows 11 connecting to PgSQl in WSL2